# screen resolution and widgets

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I set a webview so:

```
        <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500px"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

but is this correct? if the resolution of the Android phone change, I should perhaps give a height in units of percent instead in pixel?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use DP since it would "fit" into any dimmension. These links could help you:
[What is the difference between "px", "dp", "dip" and "sp" on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android)
and [Supporting Multiple Screen Resolutions Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)